# Pidyon HaBen rate

Tags: number, pregnancy-birth, mathematics, pidyon-haben, demography

About how many pidyon haben ceremonies are required to be performed per 1000 Jewish births in the past few decades?

The requirements for a pidyon haben are:

- Both parents are Israel, not Kohen or Levi.
- Son is firstborn of the mother.
- No miscarraiges (after day 40 or 39) or stillbirths before the son.
- Vaginal birth.

One way to approximate this figure would be to multiply those statistics:

> (P<sub>Israel</sub>)<sup>2</sup> * P<sub>male</sub> * (1−P<sub>earlier miscarraige or stillbirth</sub>) * P<sub>vaginal birth</sub>

Or, perhaps a better formula...

> (P<sub>Israel</sub>)<sup>2</sup> * P<sub>firstborn is a male live birth</sub> * P<sub>vaginal birth</sub>

Anyone have numbers on these?

Comment: It's 1−P(earlier miscarriage or stillbirth) not 1/P(earlier miscarriage or stillbirth). But anyway I think a more natural thing would be to count proportion of live-born births among births to yield number of _pidyonim_ (rather than count proportion of babies without an earlier stillborn birth or miscarriage).

Comment: Note that some of these numbers can't be taken from general-population numbers. Proportion of vaginal births may be different (I'm guessing significantly higher) among religious Jews than among the general population. Proportion of firstborn males may be different among _kohanim_ than among Jews (I have no reason to think so, but it's possible). The proportion of marriages between two non-Levites may be different from the square of the proportion of non-Levites. And so on.

Comment: @msh210, I'm not a math person, but even if I were, I'm not sure I'd get your first comment.  Prior stillborn births or miscarriages remove the need for a Pidyon on the next child.  I don't know if I am misunderstanding your comment or if you are forgetting that.

Comment: Charles, what's with multiplying by .5? Are you assuming half of all firstborn children are male? Is that assumption based on some information you're withholding?

Comment: @SethJ, re your comment on my comment, I'm remembering that. I think he'd be better off counting the number of firstborn live births than counting the number of first-live-born births and then discounting those with older not-live-born siblings, is all.

Comment: Another point to factor in is that not all previous miscarriages invalidate the next baby from having a pidyon haben. My wife had a miscarriage, but since it was early enough we were allowed to make a pidyon haben for the next baby with a brocha.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3897

Comment: @msh210 doesn't it make sense to count this not from the children, but from the women?  That way you can disregard all of this "older sibling" stuff...  Also, the formula is certainly meant for an approximation, not a real answer.  A less approximated answer would be even better!

Comment: @msh210 Also, as an aside, I challenge your assumption about vaginal births among Jews (note: "religious" is not a requirement for pidyon haben).  Jews as a whole tend to have children later in life and have more pressure to have kids.  This means more IVF in Jews and therefore more multiples and therefore more caesarians.

Comment: Re "doesn't it make sense to count this not from the children, but from the women? That way you can disregard all of this 'older sibling' stuff": that's roughly what I was saying. Re "'religious' is not a requirement for pidyon haben": for obligation in _pidyon_, no; for doing _pidyon_, nearly. Re "your assumption about vaginal births among Jews": it was a guess not an assumption, and I said it'd need to be checked out.

Comment: Instead of P(Israel)^2 might I propose P(maternal grandfather is Israel)*P(paternal grandfather is Israel)? The odds might be skewed one way or another - I’m not familiar with the particular odds but it could be that it’s more likely for a woman to be a Yisraelis than for a man to be a Yisrael or vice versa. While overall you’d expect there to be roughly 50-50 men and women, among the subset known as Klal Yisrael there’s clearly more women than men, hence the so-called Shidduch Crisis.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Isn't there a pidyon haben for the bechor of a bas levi and a non-Jewish father? (Your first bullet point sort of implies this, but maybe not quite...)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman and, of course, for the bechor of a bas kohen and a non-Jewish father...)

Answer (score 2):

In the United States in 2012, 1,570,976 of the 3,952,841 live births, or 39.7%, were the first live birth to that mother. Among mothers listed as non-Hispanic and white (which I mention only because I think the vast majority of Jews in the States are so listed and the category is available to me), 895,171 of the 2,134,044 live births, or 41.9%, were the first live birth to that mother. *However*, the proportion among mothers listed as white (irrespective of being listed as Hispanic) was 1,190,207 of 2,999,820, or 39.7%, and some of the considerations that lead to a higher percentage among non-Hispanic white mothers (i.e. a lower percentage — 310,326 of 907,677, or 23.2% — among Hispanic white mothers) may also lead to a lower percentage among religious Jewish mothers.

In the United States in 2012, 2,650,744 of the 3,952,841 live births, or 67.1%, and 1,441,894 of the 2,134,044 non-Hispanic white mothers' births, or 67.6%, were vaginal.

Source: [the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nvsr/nvsr62/nvsr62_09.pdf).

So, assuming that half of all babies born are male, we can use 20% as a reasonable estimate for P<sub>firstborn is a male live birth</sub> and 67% as a reasonable estimate for P<sub>vaginal birth</sub>.

According to Doron Behar, et al. in a [2003 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1180600/) in the *American Journal of Human Genetics*, citing a 1999 paper by Neil Braman et al. in *Population Specific Polymorphisms*, "it is estimated that Cohanim and Levites each comprise ∼4% of the Jewish people." Therefore, we can use 92% as a reasonable estimate for P<sub>Israel</sub>.

Therefore, we can estimate that the proportion of live births that would require a pidyon haben would be:

(P<sub>Israel</sub>)<sup>2</sup> * P<sub>firstborn is a male live birth</sub> * P<sub>vaginal birth</sub> ≈ 11%

Comment: can we really use these stats for religious jews?

Comment: @heshy, eh. With a heavy grain of salt.

Comment: @HershyS. In communities with large families, the percent of pidyon haben would be lower.