# Has anyone determined or approximated how many Cohanim entered Cana'an?

Tags: kohen-priest, census

A co-worker told me, yesterday, that he noticed that most shuls tend to have more Cohanim than Levi'im. He says that seems strange.

I can't say for what occurs in shuls, but, he did conclude that there would have had to have been fewer Cohanim than Levi'im, at least at the time *B'nai Yisra'el* entered the land of Cana'an.

Parshat Pinchas indicates the last census taken by Moshe and Elazar of those who survived the 40 years in the desert. We have a census of Levi'im above age 20, and there was obviously more than that under that age. However, only descendants of Aharon were considered Cohanim, which is a rather small percentage of that number.

Has any commentary or anyone else calculated how many Cohanim were around?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/relative-fractions-of-kohanim-and-leviim

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks. Seems like interesting Shabbat reading.

Comment: Recall that most Leviim didn’t go back to Eretz Yisrael with Ezra. That might have something to do with it. That said, his observation doesn’t match mine: in my experience, Shuls either have way too many Kohanim for the Leviim they have, or way too many Leviim for the Kohanim they have.

Comment: Offhand, I would say there were between 5-10 (or possibly up to 20, see parentheses below) Aharon, his two sons, and Pinchas make 4, any of pinchas’s sons (+ possible grandsons of Aharon after he was declared kohen gadol? I don’t remember if no grandsons but Pinchas got kehunah or if no grandsons *before* Pinchas got kehunah). Altogether this probably wouldn’t add up to more than 10 (20).

Comment: Including b’not kohen, I would say up to 15 (25).

Comment: @Loani Holy smokes! And I mean that literally ;-) Only 10 Cohanim to offer up all those sacrifices from all those people??? Man, these guys must have been overworked. Keep in mind, BTW, Aharon was not one of them who made it. Oops - that makes 9!

Comment: :-) remember, though, that until mishkan shiloh, people could sacrifice many of their own korbanos, and by the time mishkan shilo came around there must have been enough kohanim to go around. Keep in mind that by King David’s times, there were enough to split into 24 mishmarot

Comment: @Loani Baruch Hashem there were enough Cohanim then. There would have been far more had Sha'ul Hamelech not done what he did :-(